# I am using Python and I would like to find the maximum value(s) and position(s) of that(those) value(s) in a multidimensional list

Tags: python, python-3.x, max

I have a multidimensional list like this:

```
P= [ [55.0, 64.0, 71.0, 77.0, 81.0, 84.0, 85.0, 85.0, 83.0, 80.0],
    [0, 63.0, 71.0, 77.0, 82.0, 85.0, 87.0, 87.0, 86.0, 83.0],
    [0, 0, 69.0, 76.0, 81.0, 85.0, 87.0, 88.0, 87.0, 85.0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 73.0, 79.0, 83.0, 86.0, 87.0, 87.0, 85.0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 75.0, 80.0, 83.0, 85.0, 85.0, 84.0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 75.0, 79.0, 81.0, 82.0, 81.0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 73.0, 76.0, 77.0, 77.0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 69.0, 71.0, 71.0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 63.0, 64.0], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 55.0] ]
```

I would like to have a program, which finds the maximum value of this matrix, and the position of the maximum value.
In this example what I am looking for is:
Input P[], return 88.0, and 2,7

Comment: That doesn't look like a single Python list, to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/), you could use `argmax` and `unravel_index` like this:

```
import numpy as np

P = [[55.0, 64.0, 71.0, 77.0, 81.0, 84.0, 85.0, 85.0, 83.0, 80.0],
[0, 63.0, 71.0, 77.0, 82.0, 85.0, 87.0, 87.0, 86.0, 83.0],
[0, 0, 69.0, 76.0, 81.0, 85.0, 87.0, 88.0, 87.0, 85.0],
[0, 0, 0, 73.0, 79.0, 83.0, 86.0, 87.0, 87.0, 85.0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 75.0, 80.0, 83.0, 85.0, 85.0, 84.0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 75.0, 79.0, 81.0, 82.0, 81.0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 73.0, 76.0, 77.0, 77.0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 69.0, 71.0, 71.0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 63.0, 64.0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 55.0]]

P = np.array(P)
n = np.argmax(P, axis=None)
idx = np.unravel_index(n, P.shape)
print(idx)
# (2, 7)

maxval = P[idx]
print(maxval)
# 88.0
```

---

Without NumPy, you could use `max` and a list comprehension:

```
maxval, i, j = max((item, i, j)  for i, row in enumerate(P)
                                 for j, item in enumerate(row))

print(maxval)
# 88.0

print(i, j)
# (2, 7)
```

Comment: The NumPy solution will work for higher-dimensional arrays. The list comprehension solution would require some changes.

Answer (score 1):

[unutbu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16148693/262271) is great. Here's a more obvious solution you might find more intuitive.

```
curr_max = -float('inf')
curr_max_location = (None, None)
for (i, sublist) in enumerate(P):
    for (j, val) in enumerate(sublist):
        if val > curr_max:
            curr_max = val
            curr_max_location = (i, j)

print(curr_max)
print(curr_max_location)
```